# Pandas HDFStore warnings

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering why HDFStore gives warnings on string columns in pandas. I thought it may be NaNs in my real database, but trying it here gives me the warning for both columns even though one is not mixed and is simply strings.

Using .13.1 pandas and 3.1.1 tables

```
In [75]: d1 = {1:{'Mix': 'Hello', 'Good': 'Hello'}}

In [76]: d2 = {2:{'Good':'Goodbye'}}

In [77]: d2_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2,orient='index')

In [78]: d_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1,orient='index')

In [80]: d = pd.concat([d_df,d2_df])

In [81]: d
Out[81]:
      Good    Mix
1    Hello  Hello
2  Goodbye    NaN

[2 rows x 2 columns]

In [84]: d.to_hdf('test_.h5','d')
/home/cschwalbach/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.13.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/pytables.py:2446: PerformanceWarning:
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->mixed,key->block0_values] [items->['Good', 'Mix']]

  warnings.warn(ws, PerformanceWarning)
```

Answer (score 3):

When storing using the `fixed` format (which if you don't specify `format`, defaults to `fixed`), you are storing `object` dtypes (strings are stored as object dtypes in pandas). These are variable length formats which are not supported by `PyTables` in the Array types (CArray, EArray), see the warning [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#performance)

You *can* however store in a `format='table'`; see here for the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#string-columns) on storing fixed-length strings.

Comment: I have a VERY large dataframe. 20mm rows, and 40 columns. Is this the best way to try to store the DF given these parameters?

Comment: then for sure you want to use ``table`` format, as you can append and even store it in chunks; ``fixed`` is somewhat faster but you cannot append, nor query at all. read docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables (and cookbook is a link)

Answer (score 0):

The NaN value is the issue here. If you manage to replace with an empty string, the warning will go away.